# Server Tomcat v9.0 Server at localhost failed to start in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-mvc, tomcat, tomcat9

I have been trying to write basic spring mvc program just to show a static html page. I am experiencing an error which I am unable to resolve as this is my first spring-mvc program. I am using spring5.15 and apache tomcat9. I am trying to run my code but always getting exception below:

Few pointers that I would like to add:
1. I am not using maven or any dependency management tool.
2. I am adding all the jars available in Spring 5.1.5 release,javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-1.2.1,common-logging-1.2.jar and javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-api-1.2.1.

my web.xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">

    <display-name>spring-mvc-demo</display-name>

    <!-- Spring MVC Configs -->

    <!-- Step 1: Configure Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-mvc-demo-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <!-- Step 2: Set up URL mapping for Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet -->
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>




SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/spring-mvc-demo2]]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:831)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1377)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1367)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
        at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:902)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:423)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:928)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:634)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:350)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:492)
    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/spring-mvc-demo2]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:441)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1377)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1367)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
        at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:902)
        ... 21 more
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: More than one fragment with the name [spring_web] was found. This is not legal with relative ordering. See section 8.2.2 2c of the Servlet specification for details. Consider using absolute ordering.
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.web.WebXml.orderWebFragments(WebXml.java:2257)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.web.WebXml.orderWebFragments(WebXml.java:2215)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1127)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:768)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:301)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5048)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        ... 27 more

    Mar 25, 2019 5:59:15 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
    SEVERE: A child container failed during start
    java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:423)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:928)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:634)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:350)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:492)
    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:921)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:831)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1377)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1367)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
        at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:902)
        ... 13 more
    Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/spring-mvc-demo2]]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
        ... 21 more
    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/spring-mvc-demo2]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:441)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1377)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1367)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
        at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:902)
        ... 21 more
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: More than one fragment with the name [spring_web] was found. This is not legal with relative ordering. See section 8.2.2 2c of the Servlet specification for details. Consider using absolute ordering.
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.web.WebXml.orderWebFragments(WebXml.java:2257)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.web.WebXml.orderWebFragments(WebXml.java:2215)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1127)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:768)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:301)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5048)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        ... 27 more

    Mar 25, 2019 5:59:15 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
    SEVERE: The required Server component failed to start so Tomcat is unable to start.
    org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:921)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:423)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:928)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:634)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:350)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:492)
    Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
        ... 13 more
    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:921)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:831)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1377)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1367)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
        at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:902)
        ... 13 more
    Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/spring-mvc-demo2]]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
        ... 21 more
    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/spring-mvc-demo2]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:441)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1377)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1367)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
        at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:902)
        ... 21 more
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: More than one fragment with the name [spring_web] was found. This is not legal with relative ordering. See section 8.2.2 2c of the Servlet specification for details. Consider using absolute ordering.
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.web.WebXml.orderWebFragments(WebXml.java:2257)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.web.WebXml.orderWebFragments(WebXml.java:2215)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1127)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:768)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:301)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5048)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        ... 27 more**
```

Comment: How are you adding the "spring_web" dependency?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is an issue using the latest version of Tomcat 9.0.16. There were some recent changes in this version of Tomcat.

However, we can resolve this issue with the following.

In your web.xml file, on line 8 add this entry

`<absolute-ordering />`

This should appear just after the `<display-name>` entry.

For details on the `<absolute-ordering>` tag see this link

And just for completeness, here's the full file for comparison

File: web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">

   <display-name>spring-mvc-demo</display-name>
   <absolute-ordering />

   <!-- Spring MVC Configs -->
   <!-- Step 1: Configure Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet -->
   <servlet>
      <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
      <init-param>
         <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
         <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-mvc-demo-servlet.xml</param-value>
      </init-param>
      <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
   </servlet>

   <!-- Step 2: Set up URL mapping for Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet -->
   <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: I am using java based configuration and i don't have any xml files, then what should i do??

Comment: @KJEjava48 you must create one according to your case scenario. please refer https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/tomcat/tomcat-web-xml-configuration-example/

Answer (score 0):

maybe you did not add commons-logging as dependency in your project

just for more clarification read from below two links

[1.](https://crunchify.com/org-apache-catalina-lifecycleexception/)  and.  [2.](https://coderanch.com/t/655534/application-servers/Tomcat-Failed-start-java-util)

Comment: I am not using maven to build project. and I added commons-logging dependency.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same issue in Tomcat 9, I changed it to Tomcat 8.5 and also added  and it worked

Answer (score 0):

I my case i remove project that came under the tomcat server then the clean server, option available in eclipse, then I start tomcat . it worked for me.